# How to remove lines contained in file 1 from file 2 if in file 2 they are prefixed?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have the following situation:

**source.txt**

```
ID1:email1@domain1.com
ID2:email2@domain2.com
ID3:email3@domain3.com
...
```

IDs are numeric strings, e.g. `1234`, `23412`, `897`... (one or more digits).

**exclude.txt**

```
emailX@domainX.com
emailY@domainY.com
emailZ@domainZ.com
...
```

i.e. only emails, no IDs.

I want to remove all lines from **source.txt** which contain emails listed in **exclude.txt**, preserving the `ID:email` pairs for the lines which are not removed.

How can I do that with linux command line tools (or simple bash script if needed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with awk:

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}(!($2 in a))' exclude.txt source.txt
```

Alternative with grep:

```
grep -v -F -f exclude.txt source.txt
```

Use grep with care, since grep does a regex matching. You might need to add also -w option to grep (word matching)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139698/discussion-on-answer-by-george-vasiliou-how-to-remove-lines-contained-in-file-1).